# Integrating Java SE application as a service with Java EE application best practices

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, scalability

I have just started the transition from the Java SE to EE and I would like to know the best practice for the following problem.

I have a Java SE application that I would like to put up online. The web/EE part has been set up with Windows7/Apache Tomcat and standard servlet/JSP. For the Java application it is really a collection of interdependent source file.

**My plan is to create an executable .jar file that will be invoked by a servlet and the output stream and filtered error stream will be handed over to the online user.**

The factors that I have in mind are (in order of priority) :

- overhead of the .jar invocation
- consequently, high traffic handling, although it is an academic tool
- security as the invocation is with structured user input that is
  passed as command line arguments to the .jar (i am talking script
  injection type vulnerabilities as an input)
- modularity as the Java application may undergo several revision, so if there is a simpler coupling  between the app and web app I would take it without too much of the overhead stated above

So my question is whether the plan stated above, the right way of doing this? Also can anybody else think of any other factors that I should be concerned with?

Any input or pointers would be hugely appreciated!

**Edit::**
So previously I had done this project with WIn7/Apache HTTP/PHP where PHP would generate a unique file name with user input and send it off to the jar program with an exec function call and file name as command line argument. The program would generate a similar named output file and PHP would take the contents of that output file and put it back to the user. The problem was every exec call would instantiate a new JVM instance and if ever this site got a lot of user the server would crawl/crash handling those many requests. That is why I moved to a native Java server. I had the same idea here too except that I wanted the program as a unit (jar) so that any new revision would be easier to deploy. And Now this is a tentative plan up there. And that is why my question asks for the best practices on how to go about in this situation.

Comment: Sounds completely insane.

Comment: @Christopher I am completely new to Java EE. Is this not possible in the setting I have described? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your use case doesn't even seem to make sense: you want to take an executable JAR file and run it in a separate process, but you want to hook up the servlet's `InputStream` (from the client) into the external applications' `stdin` and the external application's `stdout` and pipe it into the servlet's `OutputStream` (back to the client)? That seems like an ugly mess that shouldn't have to exist. Are you trying to take a command-line program and make it runnable over the Internet?

Comment: @Christoper I understand now. Edited to explain the situation properly.

Comment: It's a perfect example of a legacy system (your command line java program) which needs to be accessed via a modern frontend (your web application). So for the proposed Java EE JSF application, you'd build a view containing the command (e.g. a button) and showing the result (e.g. a text area) and a related handler class (CDI component), which uses the logic within the JAR without going via files system, but directly providing any needed parameters, receiving the result and showing it in the view. In case it's long-running do it asynchronously and poll for the result or push it via web socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: It is **not** the right way to do it.

If you have logic available as Java SE code, e.g. as a JAR file, you can in most cases just use it within your Java EE web application.

So, if you have a servlet ready, let it use your JAR's functionality and provide the result of your method calls within the JSP.

*On a side note: If you start learning Java EE, don't bother with JSPs anymore - the default view technology today is Facelets (XHTML pages), just checkout the [Java EE 7 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-facelets.htm#GIEPX) on that topic.*

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to modularize this so that any new revision on the Java prog. would not need any change in the controller logic. But this solution should be taking care of that use case.